# How do I make this mesh curved?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am trying to make this mesh into a curved leave with the example shown in the image since I am trying to make a grass patch.

[image]

Little added question: How do I make it look more natural?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could select all, make a tip vertex active, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Active*:

[image]

Choose *Orthographic* view (<kbd>5</kbd>) and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> to switch to side view:

[image]

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> to bend:

[image]

Comment: never heard of that transform or shortcut....+1

Comment: Amazing ! Replaces proportionnal editing in that case, kinda.